# Airport Express with New Firmware 7.8 - Problems with connectivity and Airport Utility

Tags: network, wifi, airport, firmware

I have multiple Airport Express which seem to have some problems since i have updated to the new Firmware (7.8)

- The Airport Express looses Connection very often (with the old Firmware this never happend)
- If they are connected and working, The Airport Express wont show up in Airport Utility (with the old Firmware this was never a problem)

Has anybody experienced the same? Hints where I can start searching for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are connectivity issues with this new firmware, in particular when extending networks. Here are other people describing the same: 
https://discussions.apple.com/message/34061766

Right now, the solution seems to be to downgrade to the previous firmware, in case you don't want to use AirPlay 2.

I don't have any major issues when using the Airport Express just as an AirPlay 2 client, but of course this leads to loss of the extender function.